# reading a xml file with empty value in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to read a xml file in PHP and to display it.
Here's my code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("fichier.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $ibanstructure) {
foreach($ibanstructure->children() as $child){
    //echo $child->getName().";";
    if($child==""){
    echo ";";
    }
    else{
        echo $child . ";";
    }
}
echo "<br>";}
```

Here's my xml file, I will just show some rows cause there are more than 70 rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataexport product="ibanstructure" filetype="full" filedate="20160527">
<ibanstructure><tag>IS</tag><modification_flag>U</modification_flag><iban_country_code>AD</iban_country_code><iban_country_code_position>1</iban_country_code_position><iban_country_code_length>2</iban_country_code_length><iban_check_digits_position>3</iban_check_digits_position><iban_check_digits_length>2</iban_check_digits_length><bank_identifier_position>5</bank_identifier_position><bank_identifier_length>4</bank_identifier_length><branch_identifier_position>9</branch_identifier_position><branch_identifier_length>4</branch_identifier_length><iban_national_id_length>8</iban_national_id_length><account_number_position>13</account_number_position><account_number_length>12</account_number_length><iban_total_length>24</iban_total_length><sepa>N</sepa></ibanstructure>
<ibanstructure><tag>IS</tag><modification_flag>U</modification_flag><iban_country_code>AE</iban_country_code><iban_country_code_position>1</iban_country_code_position><iban_country_code_length>2</iban_country_code_length><iban_check_digits_position>3</iban_check_digits_position><iban_check_digits_length>2</iban_check_digits_length><bank_identifier_position>5</bank_identifier_position><bank_identifier_length>3</bank_identifier_length><branch_identifier_position/><branch_identifier_length>0</branch_identifier_length><iban_national_id_length>3</iban_national_id_length><account_number_position>8</account_number_position><account_number_length>16</account_number_length><iban_total_length>23</iban_total_length><sepa>N</sepa></ibanstructure>
<ibanstructure><tag>IS</tag><modification_flag>U</modification_flag><iban_country_code>KW</iban_country_code><iban_country_code_position>1</iban_country_code_position><iban_country_code_length>2</iban_country_code_length><iban_check_digits_position>3</iban_check_digits_position><iban_check_digits_length>2</iban_check_digits_length><bank_identifier_position>5</bank_identifier_position><bank_identifier_length>4</bank_identifier_length><branch_identifier_length>0</branch_identifier_length><iban_national_id_length>4</iban_national_id_length><account_number_position>9</account_number_position><account_number_length>22</account_number_length><iban_total_length>30</iban_total_length><sepa>N</sepa><optional_commence_date/><mandatory_commence_date>20151101</mandatory_commence_date></ibanstructure>
</dataexport>
```

It is kind of hard to read but this is what I get for this 3 rows when I display it with Oxygen XML Editor. I will just show some importants columns (the 1st, the 2nd, the 9th, the 10th, the 11th, the 12th, the 17th and the 18th). There are 18 columns in total.

---

```
Tag; modification_flag; ...; bank_identifier_length; branch_identifier_position;branch_identifier_length; ban_national_id_length; ...; optional_commence_date; mandatory_commence_date
```

### first row

IS; U; ...; 4; 9; 4; 8; ...; NULL; NULL

### second row

IS; U; ...; 3; NULL; 0; 3; ...; NULL; NULL

### third row

IS; U; 4; NULL; 0; 4; ...; NULL; 20151101

And this is what I get with my PHP code

---

IS;U;AD;1;2;3;2;5;4;9;4;8;13;12;24;N;

---

IS;U;AE;1;2;3;2;5;3;0;3;8;16;23;N;

---

IS;U;KW;1;2;3;2;5;4;0;4;9;22;30;N;20151101;

As you can see, when there is no value (NULL), my code doesn't show it.
We should have for the first row 18 values and not 16 with 3 ";" at the end. Same for the second row 3;;0;3 and not 3;0;3. And for the last one too.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: God damn it, I finally know what is wrong. In the original XML file, when there is no value(NULL) there is no description for this cell and Oxygen XML Editor added it for me when I clicked on the cell. That's why I don't get the correct output. I can't imagine I just spend hours on this. Now the question is how I create a ";" to indicate that a cell has no value in order to fix the gap? For many rows, the 10th column is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested, I got the below out put. It seems to be correct. Let me know is this is what the output should be.

```
IS;U;AD;1;2;3;2;5;4;9;4;8;13;12;24;N;
IS;U;AE;1;2;3;2;5;3;;0;3;8;16;23;N;
IS;U;KW;1;2;3;2;5;4;0;4;9;22;30;N;;20151101;
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I got the same output. This should be the expected output. I just notice that when there are no value for the last 2 columns, there are no descriptions in the file. But when I test it with the complete file, I don't have the same output.